# Indirect not working

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-indirect

I want to reference an external workbook that is open.   If I type `=path\[file]` directly into the cell (even though I am still asked to 'Update Values',) I am able to get the data I require.  However, I am using `INDIRECT` because the name of the file changes everyday (date).  So, I am using `CONCATENATE` to create a filename daily and then using `INDIRECT` to the cell where the concatenated formulas is.  If you paste values to see what is being generated formula, it is exactly the same formula as above, `=path\[file]`.  However, I continue to only get  #REF! error.

I read through this, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-87861952-ca9d-4d2a-a986-4d672c908d0d, and I still can not figure it out.  I had it working on my computer at home last night but today and work it is giving me trouble.

To clarify, the formula that I am trying to get to work looks like this `=INDIRECT("'"&CONCATENATE($F$129,$F$130,F95))` which worked yesterday at home.  Can someone lead me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

I have tried two options, `=INDIRECT(F121)` and `=INDIRECT("'"&F121)`. The contents of F121 have been `=CONCATENATE("'",F191,F192,F157)` and `=CONCATENATE(F191,F192,F157)`, respectively. I have also tried `=CONCATENATE("'",F191,F192,F157)` in the destination cell. F191 = `[Liquidity Risk Dashboard v2.03 -`, F192 = `=TEXT(E3,"yyyymmdd")&"]"`, and F157 = `Calculations'!D122`. If I write `='[BMI Liquidity Risk Dashboard v2.03 - 20170105]Calculations'!D122` am asked to update values but, 100% have both workbooks upon in same instance

Comment: Works as designed. `INDIRECT` does not create references to closed workbooks. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213933

Comment: @Axel Richter The workbook is open

Comment: @SozDaneron Since the workbook is open, you should not be including the full path in the `INDIRECT` call.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I am trying it with just the file to no avail.  I still get a REF! error and when I check the results of the formula against the `='[filename]Sheet'!cell`, again, they're identical.  When I insert `='[filename]Sheet'!cell` I am asked to update values but, here's the catch, whether I link the correct file or press cancel, the correct number shows up in the cell with the above formula showing when the cell is clicked.

Comment: @SozDaneron I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. I suspect there is something subtle about how you are constructing your `INDIRECT` reference string that is not being conveyed.  But without access to the details, I cannot advise further.

Comment: @SozDaneron  Since you don't share the contents of the cells you use in your argument, see if they include the single quote and exclamation point that you do NOT show in your examples.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I will provide some more information when back in work tomorrow.  I opted for some VBA but I really want to use just formulas.  I will expand a bit more when I'm back at my computer.  A problem could be that I don't have access to Bloomberg desktop which has its own Excel Add-in.  I appreciate the help and will follow up in the AM.

Comment: "When I insert `='[filename]Sheet'!cell` I am asked to update values...": Then the `filename` workbook is opened in a different `Excel` instance than the workbook you are inserting the reference. So `INDIRECT` will also not get it from this different instance. Save both files, open them from one single `Excel` instance and then try again.

Comment: @SozDaneron  When you provide this kind of information, it is much more clear if you update (edit) your original question to clarify things.  From what you write above, you have multiple unnecessary double quotes in the cells, and `F191` does **NOT** refer to the same workbook as you show in your last reference.  How did you verify that the two workbooks were open in the same instance of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've edited my original post.  Maybe some of my formatting was off in the last comment, but nothing has changed in my formulas from day one.  Regarding verifying whether the workbooks are open in the same distance, I check by clicking CTRL+Tab, is that correct?

Comment: @SozDaneron Seems like it is the same instance.  However, the workbook referenced in `F191` is still **NOT** the same workbook you show when you enter it manually. `**BMI** Liquidity Risk Dashboard v2.03 ...`  The **BMI** is mossing in F191.  You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld gosh, sorry about that.  I meant to keep that part out as it's my employer.  Cat's out the bag.  Anyhow, when I copy and paste values, I am getting my desired path, meaning, `='[BMI Liquidity Risk Dashboard v2.03 - 20170105]Calculations'!D122`.

Comment: @SozDaneron Your desired filename is missing the file extension.  See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you really have in your cells, the problem is that you are not properly naming the source workbook.

Try changing

```
F192:  =TEXT(E3,"yyyymmdd")&".xlsb]"
```

Replace `.xlsb` with whatever the file extension really is for your file.  (eg: .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls)